# Can't print as a Domain user who is however added as a Local Admin

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, active-directory, domain, windows-domain

I log on to my machine as both a local Admin and as a domain user who is however a local admin too.But login in as the domain user I can't add a printer that's shared on a PC which is on the domain, because in the Printers panel it says

**some settings are hidden or managed by your organization**

However when I log in as local Administrator I can add the printer.

when I do

> net user adminstrator

I get

> Local Group Memberships      *Administrators
>
> Global Group memberships *None

while when doing

> net user /domain username

I get

> Local Group Memberships
>
> Global Group memberships *None

I don't know if that's significant though.

Uder "lusrmgr.msc" I see that the domain user is added to the Administrator group.

Any ideas why that's happening?

Answer (score 1):

found it.

> HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

set **NoAddPrinter** to 0

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove Everyone from security when you shared a printer? If so add your user and try again. Or is that PC turned on to be visible on network?

> some settings are hidden or managed by your organization  - that is not problem.

Comment: I can add the printer whne I log in as local Admin but I can't add it as a domain user because the 'Add printer' menu is grayed out